# Python and mySQL, the UPDATE function stops the program

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm developing a system that controls some sensors and actuators in a room.
The master of this system is a Raspberry Pi, and the slaves are some Arduino Boards.

On the Raspberry Pi I've installed a web server and a MySQL database (and Python of course).

Using a web page, I can control the system, because when a click on a button (for example, "switch on the light"), the PHP page sends a query to MySQL, that update a table (`UPDATE areadati SET valore='1' WHERE nome='cmd_KA1'`).
The raspberry reads from the database every 10 ms, and if it detects a change of state, communicate with the Arduino boards for change the state of the physical actuator.
This is all OK.

But the problem is that I can't use `UPDATE` function in Python.
If the Raspberry decides (for some reasons) to switch off an actuator, it have to update the MySQL table.

When I use `cursor.execute("UPDATE areadati SET valore='0' WHERE nome='cmd_KA1'")` the program stops without errors and without crash.
The `SELECT` function is OK, but when I use `UPDATE` function the problem occurs.
The piece of code is this:

```
  import MySQLdb as mdb
  db = mdb.connect("localhost", "usrpython", "raspysqlpython", "tkn_domus")
  curs = db.cursor()
  curs.execute("UPDATE areadati SET valore='0' WHERE nome='cmd_KA1'")
```